# How to convert Image to base64 format without Losing of Image Quality?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, image-processing, base64

I have implemented two Winform Application,One application for Image to base64 Conversion and another for base64 string to Image Conversion.First i converted image to base64 string format.
Output of above application is base64 string.
for e.g code is

```
  public string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Convert Image to byte[]
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
```

In my another application(base64 to Image conversion) i converted base64 string to image,the output of this application is image.
for e.g. code is

```
 public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
```

The quality of this image is poor compare to previous image .how to resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

> The quality of this image is poor compare to previous image .how to resolve this?

Pass in an `ImageFormat` which doesn't lose quality, basically. This has *nothing* to do with the base64 encoding part - that's just a way of converting binary data to text and back. It's lossless.

To prove this to yourself, just save an image to a `MemoryStream`, rewind it and then load it from the stream - you'll see exactly the same loss of quality. Fix that, and the improvement will still be present when you use base64 to encode it as text.